# Formatting images without select

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm want to perform a variety of formatting options on images in slides.

The macro runs on images that I've SELECTED in a slide, but I'd like to run the macro without selecting the images.

Here's how I'm currently manipulating images (in this case aligning the image to the horizontal center of the slide) and the piece of code that I'm looking for help replacing:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
 .Align (msoAlignCenters), msoTrue
End With
```

Here's the entire code body so far:

```
Sub TestCenterImage()
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape

For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
 If osld.SlideIndex > 1 Then Exit Sub 'I don't know if I need this line
 For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
  If CheckIsPic(oshp) = True Then 'Making sure that we're only working with images
   With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 'The portion of code I need help with
    .Align (msoAlignCenters), msoTrue
   End With
  End If
 Next oshp
Next osld
End Sub

Function CheckIsPic(oshp As Shape) As Boolean
If oshp.Type = msoPicture Then CheckIsPic = True
 If oshp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
  If oshp.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then CheckIsPic = True
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way instead:

```
Sub TestCenterImage()
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape

For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
 'If osld.SlideIndex > 1 Then Exit Sub 'I don't know if I need this line
 For Each oShp In osld.Shapes
  If CheckIsPic(oShp) = True Then 'Making sure that we're only working with images
    CenterOnSlide oShp
   'End With
  End If
 Next oShp
Next osld
End Sub

Function CheckIsPic(oShp As Shape) As Boolean
If oShp.Type = msoPicture Then CheckIsPic = True
 If oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
  If oShp.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then CheckIsPic = True
End If
End Function

Sub CenterOnSlide(oShp As Shape)
    Dim sngSlideWidth As Single
    Dim sngSlideHeight As Single

    sngSlideWidth = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
    sngSlideHeight = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight

    oShp.Left = sngSlideWidth / 2 - oShp.Width / 2
    oShp.Top = sngSlideHeight / 2 - oShp.Height / 2


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steve, this code worked, but I have a potential complication.  While this code does effectively and accurately allow me to center an image in a slide, I was leaning towards the `With` command (operation? ) because I will want to add code in the future for other formatting changes and based on my googling it _seems_ (since I'm a novice) the `With` command is the way to go.  I look to your expertise.  Many thanks!!!

Comment: You could easily modify the CenterOnSlide routine to use With oShp and add more formatting to the shape than just centering it; or change the name entirely to reflect what you want to do with the shape.  FormatShape or whatever.  Using With/End With rather than repeatedly using oShp.ThisProperty, oShp.ThatProperty will be a bit faster.  In this case, faster but not so you'd notice any difference, but it can't hurt and it saves typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
 If osld.SlideIndex > 1 Then Exit Sub 'I don't know if I need this line
```

' If you leave that line in, your code will only touch the first slide in the presentation.
' If that's what you want, fine.  Otherwise, delete it and the matching End If below.

```
 For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
  If CheckIsPic(oshp) = True Then 'Making sure that we're only working with images
```

'       With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 'The portion of code I need help with
' Instead:
With oshp

```
    .Align (msoAlignCenters), msoTrue
   End With
  End If
 Next oshp
Next osld
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I updated the code with your suggestion and the following error was returned: "Method or data member not found" and it points to `.Align`

Comment: How I changed the code for reference, very possible that it's the source of my error: `For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
 If osld.SlideIndex > 1 Then Exit Sub
 For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
  If CheckIsPic(oshp) = True Then
   With osld.oshp
    .Align (msoAlignCenters), msoTrue
   End With
  End If
 Next oshp
Next osld
End Sub`